# Motorcycle flasher module - switching circuits (left/right flashers) using transistors

Tags: transistors, mosfet, 555

I originally posted a question about making a motorcycle flasher module using 555 timers.
With some great help from this group I successfully, kind of, got it working.
The module has four 555 timers, 2 for left, 2 for right. For each side the first timer is configured as a bistable switch to turn on/off the second timer which is configured as astable to output approx once per second.
The output of these astable timers was connected to a mosfet to flash the two 10w lamps for each side, but the mosfet(npn) was reducing the voltage and the lamps were too dim.
So I posted another question on how to go about rectifying it, here: [Driving a lamp with low-side MOSFET](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/636904/driving-a-lamp-with-low-side-mosfet)
I got some great answers and used the schematic for the P-Fet which is working perfectly.
So if everything is working ok then why another question?
Firstly, both sides are independent, which means I can have both on together, but they will flash at different times, not together like hazard lights.
Second, I realize that I could actually use just one astable 555 timer to flash either side or both together as hazard lights.
So here is how I think it might work (proposed in orange):
[image]

As previously stated, it's working with the 4 timers, I just know it can be streamlined to work better before I go ahead and make a proper pcb for it.
I appreciate your help and knowledge,
regards.

Comment: Putting a BJT there will not do what you want.

Comment: Ok, that doesn't help me understand why though. If I'm effectively putting a switch at the gate of the MOSFET then surely I'm either switching it on or off. Perhaps placing the transistor just after the 100k resistor is a better option.

Comment: I suggest using AND gates between the output of your middle 555 timer and your two transistors both labeled "Q1".  If you're running the 555's from 5V, then use regular old 74HC gates; if you're using 12V then you can use CD40xx gates.

Comment: So, I could use a cd4081, connect both the left output and central output to the 2 inputs on the And gate, the output direct to Q1 base. The same for the right and central outputs.